# Circles within button without canvas. html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to create a button which looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/b6vamcb0/3/. I'm happy with how it looks and all but I want to do it without having to use a canvas because that is just ugly. Is this possible or should I just stick with the canvas stuff?

Here's the code in case jsfiddle is down.

HTML

```
<button id="theButton1">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</button>
```

JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(51, 52, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(51, 52, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
```

CSS

```
#theButton1{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You could have an element inside the `<button>` with `border-radius: 50%; border: 10px solid white;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a element inside that would be the white circle:

```css
#theButton1{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#circle{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 60%; 
  border: 12px solid white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="theButton1">
        <div id="circle"></div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick JSFiddle example of how you can achieve the desired result.

https://jsfiddle.net/sjgaajgp/2/

```
<div class="button">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Taking advantage of `display: table` and `display: table-cell` the circle can be positioned perfectly in the centre of the button element.

```
.button {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    display: table;
}

.button .circle {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Spencer Wieczorek's answer seems a little more simple though so I'll go with that.

Comment: Upvote because your answer works also...even if a bit more verbose.